# Can we add before filters before method calls?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, rails-activerecord, before-filter

Take this Ruby on Rails example.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :generateRandomValue

  def generateRandomValue
     //generates a random value between 0 and 10
  end

  def getBoo
     //Return value generated by the method above
   end
end
```

If we call `getBoo`, class will run `generateRandomValue` first because it has a general scoped before filter.

We can also tweak this before filters in Ruby on Rails, like;

```
    method x,y,z runs before a method.
    method 1,2,3 runs before b,c,d method.
    method always, always runs. (think it like PHP's __construct())
```

Is there any way to set before filters before controller method calls in Laravel 4?

The main reason is, I want to DRY most of my code by applying before filters.

Thank you.

Comment: yes it is possible. have you read the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - this is a new feature in Laravel 4.

Taylor [has a good video on it here you can watch](http://vimeo.com/52964368) - which shows it in action and the code to use.

But in general you just add a filter to your constructor:

```
Class ExampleController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('myfilter');        
        $this->beforeFilter('anotherfilter')->only('getBoo');       
    }
}
```